# Embedding perl in verilog

Tags: perl, emacs, verilog, system-verilog

Looking for a way to automate generation of repetitive verilog code using perl and verilog autos and without using generate statements.

Specifically, I'd like to do this:

All that is within `AUTOMATE_THIS` comment section should be generated when I call verilog `AUTO`s in emacs. Of course, I can write a perl script and run it outside of my emacs session, reload the buffer and then do the verilog `AUTO` expansion but I'd like to do this single shot.

```
module foo (/*AUTOARG*/);

    parameter NUM=7; // Number of ops

    input clk;

    /*AUTOMATE_THIS
    $num=$PARAMS{NUM};
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i=$i+1) {
    FILE<<print

    }
    FILE    
    */
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can do something with generate statements, use them.  If you can't (say, if you want a parametrizable number of ports), then you will probably have to write a script to generate the verilog from a template.  You'll have to run the script manually whenever you need to make changes.

Here is an example of what you can do in Python, I'm sure you can do something similar in whatever language you prefer: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-axis/blob/553547f661f54153e618ebf8297f6e4f92253e6e/rtl/axis_mux.py .

Answer (score 1):

> All that is within AUTOMATE_THIS comment section should be generated when I call verilog AUTOs in emacs.

You can do this with emacs lisp:

```
(defun AUTO()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "    /*AUTOMATE_THIS
    $num=$PARAMS{NUM};
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i=$i+1) {
    FILE<<print

    }
    FILE    
    */")))
```

Point the cursor before the last parenthesis then evaluate this function with

```
C-x C-e
```

To use this function,

```
M-x AUTO
```

AUTOMATE_THIS comment section will be generated and be able to do it single shot.

Answer (score 1):

No pre-processor will be able to deal with different instances of `foo` that override `NUM` with different values. You **must** use `generate` statements for that.

But if you are just looking for a pre-processor where you can define macros with loops, here are a few suggestions.

- https://github.com/aandyl/vp3/wiki/Manual
- http://vbpp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.0-6/

Most of these are fairly old, as most people have come to realize the `generate` does what they need. Also SystemVerilog has many new constructs that make these less necessary.